# Good documentation or links for sharepoint performance testing and load testing in azure

Tags: 2013, load-testing

Hi can anyone share the good documentation and links for sharepoint performance testing and load testing techniques in azure , i want to to load testing and performance testing for my sharepoint internet portal in azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint is a web-based application therefore you don't need any specific instructions, any good guide on web applications load testing will play for you. If you don't have anything in mind check out [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx)

Given Microsoft technology stack the most obvious tool choice would be [Microsoft Visual Studio Load Testing Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540(v=vs.110).aspx), however if there are licensing constraints you can also consider one of [free and open source load testing tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use), once you stick to one of the tools inspect its documentation to learn how to implement a well-behaved load test

Comment: if i do load test from visual studio and i have 4 web front end servers & load balancer  there is equal load sent to these 4 servers through load balancer.

Comment: It mostly depends on your load balancer configuration, there are several common algorithms (round-robin, sticky sessions, random, etc.). Well-behaved load balancer should evenly distribute the load between alive and active backend servers